# Where do I properly put my constants in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I usually follow the [unofficial Meteor FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files) on how to structure my codebase, but I can't figure out where I should put my global constants.

To give an example: I have some database entries with a constant GUID that I need to reference in many points of my app. So far I just attached the constants to the relevant collection, such that in `collections/myCollectionWithGuids.coffee` it would say:

```
@MyCollectionWithGuids = new Meteor.Collection "myCollectionWithGuids"

@MyCollectionWithGuids.CONSTANT_ID = "8e7c2fe3-6644-42ea-b114-df8c5211b842"
```

This approach worked fine, until I need to use it in the following snippet, located in `client/views/myCollectionWithGuidsView.coffee`, where it says:

```
Session.setDefault "selectedOption", MyCollectionWithGuids.CONSTANT_ID
```

...which is unavailable because the file is being loaded *before* the Collections are created.

So where should I put my constants then, such that they are *always loaded first* without hacking in a bunch of subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rely on the fact that a directory names `lib` is always treated first when it comes to load order.

So I would probably advise you to organize your code as follow :

```
lib/collections/collection.js
client/views/view.js
```

In your particular use case this is going to be okay, but you might find cases when you have to use `lib` in your client directory as well and as the load order rules stack (subdirectories being loaded first), it will be loaded BEFORE the `lib` folder residing in your project root.

For the moment, the only way to have full control over the load order is to rely on the package API, so you would have to make your piece of code a local package of your app (living in the `packages` directory of your project root).

It makes sense because you seem to have a collection and a view somehow related, plus splicing your project into a bunch of collaborative local packages tends to be an elegant design pattern after all.

Creating a local package is really easy now that Meteor 0.9 provide documentation for the `package.js` API.

http://docs.meteor.com/#packagejs

Answer (score 1):

I would put your collection definitions in a `lib` directory. [File structure documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp) explains that all files under the `lib` directory get loaded before any other files, which means your variable would be defined when you attempt to access it in your client-side code.

Generally speaking, you always want your collections to be defined before anything else in your application is loaded or executed, since your application will most likely heavily depend upon the use of the collection's cursor.